# Selenium Webdriver - accessing data from dynamic table

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am automating some of the functional test cases in a web application using Selenium webdriver and Java. I have a form where I can add new employee. When a new employee is added, the added employee details can be seen in another page. I want to verify the added employee details and finally delete the employee from the view page. 
Each of the added employee details are showing in separate tables in the view page. The xpath of each table is as follows

```
.//*[@id='contentSec']/div/div[1]  
.//*[@id='contentSec']/div/div[2]
.//*[@id='contentSec']/div/div[3]
and so on...
```

The issue is that how can I get the xpath of the last added employee table in order to verify employee details. I can't search using employee name or any employee details since multiple employees may have same details. I want a generalized method to access the employee details that should work always. I used

```
List<WebElements> elements=driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='contentSec']/div"));
```

but

```
elements.size();
```

always returns 1 even if multiple tables exists. Is there any method to access last added employee details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are missing the `/div` at the end to get inner `div`s inside a parent `div`:

```
.//*[@id='contentSec']/div/div
```

> Is there any method to access last added employee details?

In this case, you can use `last()`:

```
.//*[@id='contentSec']/div/div[last()]
```

Comment: Tried above code, but there are some issues. If I delete the employee with  table xpath './/*[@id='contentSec']/div/div[2]', then 'elements.size();' returns 3, it should have been 2

Comment: @user5912043 okay, sure, updated. Please check it out.

Answer (score 0):

So ,You are doing a small mistake in your approach of finding elements.

it should be `findElements` and not `findElement`

```
List<WebElements> elements=driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='contentSec']/div"));
```

`driver.findElement` will always look for the first accurance of the element thats why you are always getting `1` when trying to get the `size` using `elements.size()`

Comment: Sorry!!...it was a mistake in my code, I have updated it